# Can I find and import files into an Ant buildfile at run time?

Tags: xml, plugins, ant, build-automation

I want to create an Ant buildfile, that includes some files as a sort of plugin.

So if I want to activate a feature in a project - say pmd-checking - I copy a pmd.xml in a directory and the build.xml get on the start the idea, that pmd.xml exists and imports it, so that new targets can be available to the build.

But the 'import' task can only be used as a top-level task, so I have no idea how to relize this functionality. Is this possible with Ant and if so, how can I do it?

EDIT: I would prefer a solution, that allows new targets to show up in the listing presented by `ant -p`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not explicitly stated in the import task documentation, but the task accepts a fileset as an alternative to a single file.
Hence this, at the top level, should do the trick, and targets created are listed by `ant -p`:

```
<property name="plugins.dir" value="plugins" />
<fileset id="plugin.modules" dir="${plugins.dir}">
    <include name="**/*.xml" />
</fileset>

<import>
    <fileset refid="plugin.modules" />
</import>
```

One wrinkle with this is that there must be at least one plug-in in the 'plugins' directory, or the import will fail.
You can just create a placeholder file - say called `empty.xml`:

```
 <project />
```

Once that's there, you just need to put any new plug-ins in the plugin directory, and they will be imported by future builds.

Answer (score 3):

You can use the [**ant**](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/ant.html) task and even parameterize the target name. Here's an example:

```
<ant antfile="plugins/pmd.xml" target="${pmd-target}"/>
```

If you want more flexibility, I recommend checking [gant](http://gant.codehaus.org/) or [gradle](http://www.gradle.org/).

Comment: That is a possible solution, but the new targets aren't present in the listing of 'ant -p'.

Answer (score 3):

In the documentation for the [import](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/import.html) task, note the `optional` attribute.  Set this to `true` and missing includes won't break the build.

So `pmd.xml` is included if found, but won't break the build if it isn't.

Not tested, so I'm not positive about `ant -p` including targets in the imported file if it is found.

Comment: 'ant -p' lists target defined in imported files. I didn't see this attribute, this helps a bit. But I would prefer, if I can obtain the plugins at runtime.

Comment: How is the build file to know when to include the file?  You'll either need to pass a property as a parameter and put some conditional targets in the build file. That will only work on execution, not with the "-p" option".

Please give more detail on the use case.

Comment: I want to include all antfiles in a given directory or matched by a pattern. I see, there is no perfect solution, but I can combine your solution and the answer from Miguel Ping to catch most cases.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure want you want is conceptually possible. The `-p` command-line argument doesn't execute any tasks, it just parses the file. What you want would require something to be executed.

But, I'd give the [ant-contrib](http://ant-contrib.sourceforge.net/) project a look. It has a conditional [`<if>`](http://ant-contrib.sourceforge.net/tasks/tasks/if.html) task, which might make the top-level import work only when you want it to.